# Delete folders older than X within zip file

Tags: powershell

I am trying to delete folders which are older than a certain date. These folders are in a zip file which is laid out like so:

`<Zip Folder>
    <Folder 1>
       <Folder 2>
       <Folder 3>
       <Folder 4>`

Folders 2, 3 and 4 may not need all deleted so I cannot just delete the main zip file. I have tried this but it dosen't seem to do anything:

```
function DeleteAuditFiles{
# The two parameters. 
param([string]$limit, [string]$path)

$zips = Get-ChildItem -Path $path -recurse *.zip

foreach ($zipfile in $zips) {

    $stream = New-Object IO.FileStream($zipfile.FullName, [IO.FileMode]::Open)
    $mode   = [IO.Compression.ZipArchiveMode]::Update
    $zip    = New-Object IO.Compression.ZipArchive($stream, $mode)

    ($zip.Entries | ? { $_.PSIsContainer -and $_.CreationTime  -lt $limit }) | % { $_.Delete() }

    $zip.Dispose()  
    $stream.Close() 
}
}
```

Comment: Have you tried using `Remove-Item $_.FullName -Force -Recurse` in stead of `$_.Delete()`

Comment: @Chard I tried that and it does not seem to be working either, I am not sure if my code is correct in identifying each folder. Thanks for your help

Comment: Get it to print out all of the file paths using `Write-Host $_.FullName`

Comment: These are not items generated by `Get-ChildItem` so I don't think you can use `$_.PSIsContainer` to determine if it's a folder. Also a Zip entry has `LastWriteTime`, not `CreationTime`.

Comment: I changed this `($zip.Entries | ? { !$_.PSIsContainer -and $_.CreationTime  -lt $limit }) | % { Write-Host $_.FullName}` and it gives me a list of the files to be deleted, which would be even better rather than the folder, however the remove-item dosent do anything and using solely delete removes everything.

Comment: I have realised that `$_.FullName` is not giving me the full path hence the files not being deleted, any idea how to get the full path please?

Comment: What PowerShell version do you need for the assembly `[IO.Compression.ZipArchiveMode]`. I'm having issues testing this code

Comment: I was able to add the type `IO.Compression.ZipArchive` with PS V3. Then `[IO.Compression.ZipArchiveMode]` was working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had to add a type to use `IO.Compression.ZipArchive`:

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.IO.Compression
```

See if this works:

```
      $toDelete = $zip.Entries | where{ $_.name -eq "" -and $_.LastWriteTime  -lt $limit } 
      $toDelete | % { $_.Delete() }
```

I used a variable, because you need to get all the folders you want to delete in a list first, if you delete while enumerating, Powershell will complain with an exception:

```
An error occurred while enumerating through a collection: Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute..
```

Comment: Work of caution with `$_.PSIsContainer -and $_.CreationTime  -lt $limit` where clause. I think OP will been to use brackets to get the desired outcome. `$_.PSIsContainer -and ($_.CreationTime  -lt $limit)`. FYI

Comment: Yes, I noticed in the entries that folders had an empty name, hence the `$_.name -eq ""`. Also, the OP will need to remove the files within each folders, as those entries won't be removed by the removal of the parent folder.